# Modern-CV: making the part where dates are broader

Tags: moderncv

So suppose I have a structure like the following in my CV:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{red} 
\usepackage[top=1.2in, bottom=1.05in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{x}{x}
\mobile{x}
\email{x@gmail.com}
\photo[0pt][0pt]{Me.jpg} 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle 
\section{Random Section}
    \cventry{04/16--Present}{Very important Job}{University X}{}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

In the output, the word "Present" is put on a new line in the first column. I would like to make this column broader, such that it is put on the same line as the starting date. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add or uncomment in the example file the command `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}` to change the width of the first column containing dates of your cv.

With the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{red} 
\usepackage[top=1.2in, bottom=1.05in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % <==================================

\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{x}{x}
\mobile{x}
\email{x@gmail.com}
%\photo[0pt][0pt]{example-image} 

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle 
\section{Random Section}
    \cventry{04/16--Present}{Very important Job}{University X}{}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

you get the result

[image]